# is ReadWriteOnce thread safe?

Tags: spring, docker, kubernetes, containers

I tried to search and look for resources regarding this, but i found that `ReadWriteOnce` mode allows a node to read and write once. A node consists of many  pods and that's what i'm confused about because pods can read or write, is this process going to be scheduled ?.

What i'm really trying to achieve is `thread safety`!
since there's one master who can write to this shared volume and many nodes should read after.

Answer (score 1):

`ReadWriteOnce` is an access mode and access modes dictate how many nodes can mount the PersistentVolume, and with which capabilities (read/write) - but *not* the amount of operations it can perform against that volume. Thus, your statement "i found that ReadWriteOnce mode allows a node to read and write once" is inaccurate.

From the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes):

> ReadWriteOnce
>
> the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node. ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to access the volume when the pods are running on the same node.

So no, this has nothing to do with synchronizing access to the underlying storage.